# Error in (function (formula, data = NULL, subset = NULL, na.action = na.fail,: invalid type (list) for variable 'Dept'

Tags: r, plot

I'm still learning R, and it's been a long time since I used it the last time.
Also I tried to prepare the CSV - Table right, but that's maybe the reason why it"s not working.

So first: I have marine sediment samples from different depts and locations. I counted the microfossils and listed them according to their species.

For example:

ID      Species    Quantity Dept
MB36    Ammonia b. 0    43
MB36    Ammonia spp.    6   43
MB36    Ammotium s. 39  43
MB36    Bulimina e. 6   43
MB38    Ammonia b.  0   36
MB38    Ammonia spp.    4   36
MB38    Ammotium s. 7   36
MB38    Bulimina e. 0   36
...

I load the table in, summary works fine.
I'd attached it and tried the first plot.

```
plot(Quantity~Dept, main="Anzahl auf Tiefe", pch=15+as.numeric(Species), col=c("darkgoldenrod1","darkseagreen", "lightgoldenrodyellow")[as.numeric(Species)])
```

And there is the error:

```
Error in (function (formula, data = NULL, subset = NULL, na.action = na.fail, : invalid type (list) for variable 'Dept'
```

I have no idea what to change.

Comment: Sounds like you imported or transformed your data incorrectly at some point but you haven't shared the relevant code. Please see [how to create a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for ways to include your data as a `dput()` for example to see what's really going on.

Comment: I solved it myself :) the problem was that I named the Data.frame "Dept" too. So R didn't know that I meant the col. Thanks for the comment though :)